# Learning Ruby on Rails. Syntax issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I'm new to Ruby, Rails and programming in general, so please forgive me if the question is very trivial.
I have this view:

```
<h1>Listing products</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>\</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.\ %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>
```

When I try to access the link `http://localhost:3000/products` I receive an error:

```
 SyntaxError in Products#index

Showing C:/Sites/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #13 raised:

C:/Sites/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...tput_buffer.append= ( product.\ );@output_buffer.safe_concat...
...                               ^
C:/Sites/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'); end 
       ^
C:/Sites/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
C:/Sites/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Extracted source (around line #13):

10: 
11: <% @products.each do |product| %>
12:   <tr>
13:     <td><%= product.\ %></td>
14:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
15:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
16:     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/products/index.html.erb
```

I was just following an example in a book to learn Rails, so basically I've done nothing to code this view.
Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: What is this `<td><%= product.\ %></td>`? Is `\` a `@product`'s attribute? Seems like you should call some attribute instead of backslash.

Comment: What are you trying to do with <%= product.\ %> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rails generates very useful logs. Read it once it gives you line number and file name.

replace <%= product.\%> with <%= product.name %> where name is the attribute of product.

Comment: Don't worry about logs, install better_errors https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors

Comment: If I do this, I get another error: `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `<%= product.name %>` (substitute in desired attribute) instead of `<%= product.\ %>`

The little tiny caret under the the incorrect syntax gives you an indication of what is tripping the error.

Comment: If I do this, I get another error: `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: That means `@products` is nil, make sure you type all required code provided by books. I just finish that example yesterday, it works fine.

Comment: Yes, you need to put @products = Product.all (or whatever) in your products_controller.rb

Comment: Here is the piece of my products_controller:

`class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end`

Comment: after "@products = Product.all" line add a logger.info "=====#{@products.inspect}" and check that whether it's nil or not...if it's nil then obviously u will get a error in view and need to solve that logical error in ur controller...:)

Comment: Hi, well, I wasn't sure if you'd actually defined @products in your controller, and by having you run Product.all I could at least check your model definition and database schema

Comment: There were problems with gems. Sorry for all the trouble and thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the code # app\views\products\index.html.erb" as follows:

```
  <h1>Listing products</h1>

<table>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">

    <td>
      <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %>
    </td>

    <td class="list_description">
      <dl>
        <dt><%= product.title %></dt>
        <dd><%= truncate(strip_tags(product.description),
               length: 80) %></dd>
      </dl>
    </td>

    <td class="list_actions">
      <%= link_to 'Show', product %><br/>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %><br/>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete,
                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New product', new_product_path %>
```

Rewrite the code # app\controllers\products_controller.rb as follows:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/new
  # GET /products/new.json
  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product,
          notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created,
          location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /products/1
  # PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to @product,
          notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```